# Lua access table with variable amount of keys

Tags: lua

Take a look at this example code:

```
tbl = {
    status = {
        count = 0
    }
}

function increase(t, ...)
    -- ???
end

increase(tbl, "status", "count") -- increases tbl["status"]["count"] by 1
```

I want to be able to dynamically access the table entries via a variable amount of string keys, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Just keep indexing as long as you have arguments and haven't hit a non-table. Have you tried writing the function?

Comment: Yes I've tried writing it but ended up only with the value reference of the entry which I obviously can't assign to, could you show me your solution?

Comment: Show your attempt and explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: `tbl = {
    status = {
        count = 0
    }
}

function increase(t, ...)
local target = t
for i, key in pairs({...}) do
target = target[key]
end
-- target is a reference to the value of the entry so I can't assign to it
end`

Comment: Update the post with the code and the exact problem. And the problem isn't that you have a reference. It is that you *don't* have a reference. You have a value. You don't want to update the local variable you want to update the last table directly.

Comment: Thank you, figured out how to do it.

Comment: Can you take a look at my solution?

Comment: tbl.status.count = tbl.status.count + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tbl = {
    status = {
        count = 0
    }
}

function increase(t, ...)

    local target = t 
    local args = {...}  
    local last = "" 

    for i, key in pairs(args) do
        if i == #args then
            last = key
        else
            target  = target[key]
        end
    end

    target[last] = target [last] + 1
end

increase(tbl, "status", "count") -- increases tbl["status"]["count"] by 1
```

Comment: Need to use `ipairs` though, and maybe compute `#args` just once

Answer (score 4):

That's what recursion is for:

```
function increase(t, k1, k2, ...)
    if k2 == nil then
        t[k1] = (t[k1] or 0) + 1
    else
        if t[k1] == nil then
            t[k1] = { } -- remove this to disable auto-creation
        end
        increase(t[k1], k2, ...)
    end
end

local t = { }
increase(t, "chapter A", "page 10")
increase(t, "chapter A", "page 13")
increase(t, "chapter A", "page 13")
increase(t, "chapter B", "page 42", "line 3");

function tprint(t, pre)
    pre = pre or ""
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            print(pre..tostring(k))
            tprint(v, pre.."  ")
        else
            print(pre..tostring(k)..": "..tostring(v))
        end
    end
end

tprint(t)
```

output:

```
chapter A
  page 10: 1
  page 13: 2
chapter B
  page 42
    line 3: 1
```